# FTDI Unrecognized USB device

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, ftdi

I connected my FTDI (FT232RL) to my PC, windows 8.1. And it gave me a notification saying "USB device not recognized". However, I thought that the problem is from the cable that I am using to connect my FTDI with my PC, I tried another cable, same results. I am trying to program an ESP32-CAM, which has no boot loader, nor a way to connect it directly with the PC. However, I tried to upload the program (from arduino IDE) to the FTDI, It has said "Could not open port COM4", I have concluded that if I can only bypass this error, the upload will work fine with no errors. Windows is preventing any communication with this device, because it has not recognized it yet.

I have tried the following:

1. I reinstalled the FTDI driver using the '.exe' setup file, and installed many version many times.
2. I replaced the cable with another cable, because I suspected that the cable had an issue, but it made no difference.
3. I checked the wiring 10 times, nothing suspicious.
4. I have also tried to choose the driver manually from the device manager tab and downloaded the driver from the [FTDI website](https://www.ftdichip.com), still did not work. There was a guide on how to do the "setting the driver up for the FTDI", I followed it, did not work too, but I followed the "Setting up the driver manually" part, there was a step that was not obvious enough for me, he chose a file that contains the driver, but which file exactly? only god knows.

However, I found some videos on the internet that does not require any driver (Linux sometimes work without any driver). Why is that? Why am I getting this? Why does other people are not getting this error? I saw a lot of people suffering from this FTDI chip. There should be a solution.

Comment: does the module use a genuine FTDI chip?

Comment: I really don't know, how can I even know if it is genuine or not? I bought it from aliexpress.com, most people gave the seller a good feedback for that product.

Comment: If it's from a cheap chinese site then it's probably fake.

Comment: check the FTDI site ... they may have a program that you can download and use to identify if your device is genuine

Comment: Do you have the product link?

Comment: @Fahad , https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32645814447.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.27424c4dL473Vv , I think it is genuine, most people gave positive feedback.

Comment: It is possible that you just got a bad board. You can use this utility software: https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Utilities.htm#FT_PROG
to configure FTDI ICs. Give this a try. If this can't detect it, well, you will have to order again.

Comment: Alright then, nothing worked out for the FTDI chip, I have concluded that my chip is fried. However, I want to answer this question, but there is not a clear solution. So, I am thinking of closing this question.